# d3 selection issue offsetParent is null

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get the offsetParent id using d3 selection (I've had a similar question before but the answer does not work here for some reason).

When I console log d3.select(this) the log is:

```
[Array[1]]
    0: Array[1]
        0: g
          offsetParent: div#divID
              id: "divID"
```

How do I get the id starting from d3.select(this)?

I want to do:

```
d3.select(d3.select(this).select("g").node().offsetParent).attr("id")
```

but get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetParent' of null
```

when it is not null. I must be selecting incorrectly.

Comment: It's better to know what `this` is, but it seems it should just be `$(this).attr('id')` ? Assuming you use jQuery.

Comment: [offsetParent](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-htmlelement-interface) is an HTML thing. `<g>` elements are SVG. You seem to be relying on a Chrome bug here.

Comment: Yep, it was the g selection that was messing everything up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The g selection is what is causing the issue. This selection:

```
d3.select(d3.select(this).node().offsetParent).attr("id")
```

solved the issue for me.